# javascript 2d tile based game rendering (terraria-style)

Tags: javascript, canvas, dictionary, 2d, tile

I have made terraria clones in the past. They're quite fun as a project, I find. But with the 1.2 update of Terraria, I want a clone that I can run on any computer anywhere anytime. So I'm working with HTML5.

At first, I thought it would be simple - as it has been in the past with the other languages I've used.

But once I got into it, I started facing many problems. I do NOT have any code to share, because I've deleted it all and tried again countless times. I can only do edits on my website live, so when I want to try again, I either make a new page entirely, or just edit the page I currently have. For lack of unlimited storage, I edit the page I currently have.

Some pseudo code for what I have tried is this:

Set the fillStyle to black.
Loop through the width and height/16 and create x amount of rect()'s.
Fill all the rects.
Draw the player (either with an image or another rect in a different colour).

Which works fine, I can render it all just great. But it takes a lot longer than I would like. I'd be getting about .4FPS if I used this for rendering. So what I'm wondering, is how can I go about rendering a 2d tile based map that extends past the area of the viewport efficiently?

I don't want theories, I know the concepts. I need help understanding how to IMPLEMENT the concepts. Some code that does this quasi efficiently would be fantastic to see.

EDIT:

I can only do edits live because I use a chromebook. There is no option for me to use a text editor and then upload the files when they're completed.

Comment: I can't give you an answer (don't know too much about it), but check out this game made with HTML5 http://playbiolab.com/.  Perhaps something about it will be useful to you.

Comment: Why not use jsfiddle.net or some similar site that not allow you to save what you do but also to share it here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you rendered the whole thing once then you would get less lag.
Maybe have 16x16 grids within the whole map that can be saved and then rendered as a whole as needed?
You could (re)render them when they are modified and when they first appear.

Comment: In the past month, I've managed to do this somewhat efficiently in Javascript, but I'm still unable to figure out how to move a camera around on the map, I am restrained to the confines of the viewport currently. Which is alright, I can get a lot of the physics/logic mostly done here. But I do want a scrollable game at some point.. Meh, I can figure it out probably. :P

Comment: SUPER late on this, but you can use the canvas method called transform(xOffset, yOffset) to "move" the stuff around.

Answer (score 0):

I did exactly this for a similar game as well. One thing that I noticed was with very large maps, it took a long time to draw the entire background again. Instead, make multiple canvas elements and only draw the background once. Then draw the player and enemies (and other non-static tiles) on top of that using another canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I merely use [scratch.mit.edu](http://scratch.mit.edu) for the coding. Now the canvas element seems just wrong. It just was this: `<canvas width="840" height="1244"></canvas>`. It had nothing in it. But, I did discover something very disturbing. Now when I said the `<canvas>` element was blank, I wasn't completely right. It also had the element `<iframe>` but it also was empty. It did however have a source (src) viewing this:

```js
<iframe src="svg://#7382939238578,9234973905703426598345345.3457178293748298384923.23749824.2374932.773.210597348347239" id="SVG"&gt;&lt;input src="terraria-stamped.html"></iframe>
```

So, I came up with this kind of terraria. 2D, Player designer (maybe won't work), `Terraria` Font (also maybe won't work), and so far, a map (X mar-x the spot). Also, I added Crimson (got that idea from Griffpatch) but it spawns underground. It's spawn radius is 184 tiles right of spawn, and 156 tiles left of spawn. NPC's can't have houses there. To view the story.

```js
<a href="http://www.sites.google.com/ucaes.org/terrariacode/">click here.</a>
```